# How do I tell what is part of a route is the controller and what is just a sub folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

When looking at an MVC page and looking at the form action I can see it is set to:

> /admin/WikiAdmin/edit/

So I spent my time looking for a controller called **admin**. I looked in the routes in the global and nothing was there.

Eventually I found that this url actually maps to the **WikiAdmin** controller which is confusing. Do does this mean you can have controllers in sub-folders?  How does the app know **not** to forward the request to the admin controller and to actually send it to the **WikiAdmin** controller?

Comment: You can have areas. If I've understood the concept correctly an area is sort of a separate MVC application runing as a subfolder to your original MVC-application, though if you can have controllers in subdirectories I don't know. You can also of cause set up routes that makes the url have nothing at all to do with controller or directories at all.

Answer (score 1):

The `admin` part of the url is called `area`. You could read more about areas in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx). And a [video here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/aspnet-mvc-2-areas). Basically areas allow you to group multiple controllers sharing some common functionality on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have controllers in sub-folders. With routing it could be a lot of possible URLs.
For example, if you have a route registered as below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "admin1",
    "admin/{controller}/{action}/",
    new { controller = "WikiAdmin", action = "Index"}
);
```

The url can be **/admin/WikiAdmin/Index/** or **/admin/WikiAdmin/Edit/** or something else that matches the route. (Assume that there is an Edit action in WikiAdmin controller)

More example, if you have a route registered as below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "admin2",
    "account/{action}/", //no controller specified in url
    new { controller = "WikiAdmin", action = "Index"}
);
```

Then the url can be **/account/Index/** or **/account/Edit/** or even **/account/**. (Because default controller is WikiAdmin and default action is Index)

Comment: The point is that the URL patterns in ASP.Net MVC are entirely customizeable. So you need to study the route mappings closely to determine which one fits the URL. One could do away entirely with the conventions and develop her/his own patterns. For example, in one very data-driven app I wrote, I have almost all URLs mapped to the following pattern: "{region}/{section}/{topic}" and the controller and action are specified in the 3rd param of MapRoute, like here Edison's example.